# Windows Service e processo de auto-atualização sendo acusado de vírus pelo Avast

Tags: delphi, ftp, delphi-6, antivirus

Minha aplicação **Windows Service** feita em Delphi 6 está sendo acusada como vírus pelo **Avast** no processo de auto-atualização.

Logo quando o processo de construção do executável, após o *build*, é terminado o Avast já acusa vírus. Ele acusa o **Win32:Evo-gen [Susp]**.

O processo é por meio de uma *thread* e por esse método:

```pascal
procedure TThreadAutoUpdate.Update;
var
  fileDownload: TFileStream;
  bDownloaded: boolean;
  fileBat: TStringList;
  cAppName: string;
  cBatName: string;
begin
  cAppName := Application.ExeName;
  if FileExists(cAppName+'.tmp') then
    DeleteFile(PChar(cAppName+'.tmp'));
  FileDownload := TFileStream.Create(cAppName+'.tmp', fmCreate);
  try
    AddLog('Logando ...');
    FIdFTP.Host := 'ftp://fakeDeDownload.com.br';
    FIdFTP.{$if CompilerVersion < 16}User{$else}Username{$ifend} := 'update';
    FIdFTP.Password := 'update';
    FIdFTP.Connect({$if CompilerVersion < 16}true{$ifend});
    try
      FIdFTP.Get('MyService.exe', FileDownload);
      AddLog('Efetuando download ...');
      if FIdFTP.Connected then
        FIdFTP.Disconnect;
      bDownloaded := True;
    except
      on e: Exception do
      begin
        bDownloaded := False;
        AddLog('Não foi possível atualizar o serviço');
        AddLog('Motivo: ' + e.Message);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(FileDownload);
  end;

  if bDownloaded then
    begin
      AddLog('Download efetuado');
      AddLog('Trocando os executáveis');
      fileBat := TStringList.Create;
      try
        fileBat.Clear;
        cBatName := THelpers.GetTempDirectory + ExtractFileName(cAppName) + '.bat';
        fileBat.Add('net stop MyServiceSvc');
        fileBat.Add(':Label1');
        fileBat.Add('@echo off');
        fileBat.Add('del "'+cAppName+'"');
        fileBat.Add('taskkill /f /im "'+ ExtractFileName(cAppName) +'"');
        fileBat.Add('if Exist "' + cAppName + '" goto Label1');
        fileBat.Add('Move "'+cAppName+'.tmp'+'" "'+cAppName+'"');
        fileBat.Add('net start MyServiceSvc');
        fileBat.Add(':Label2');
        fileBat.Add('del "' + cBatName + '"');
        fileBat.Add('if Exist "' + cBatName + '" goto Label2');
        fileBat.SaveToFile(cBatName);
        WinExec(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(cBatName)), SW_HIDE);
        AddLog('Atualização efetuada com sucesso');
      finally
        fileBat.Free;
      end;
    end;
end;
```

Mas se eu deixar exatamente essa linha comentada, então o executável já não é acusado:

```pascal
// FIdFTP.Get('MyService.exe', FileDownload);
```

Alguém tem ideia do que pode estar ocorrendo?

Comment: A forma mais simples é contornar o comando que está gerando o falso positivo, a mais complexa é mandar pra tudo quanto é antivírus um alerta de falso positivo.

Comment: Sugiro que você também replique essa pergunta no SOEN com a tag Indy pro [Remy Lebeau](http://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) dar uma olhada. Afinal, é o pai da criança.

Comment: Você já tentou deixar a função fora da thread? Fazer uma function BaixaArquivo? Aqui não deu falso positivo no avast.

Comment: Exatamente. Para detectar uma assinatura de virus, o mecanismo precisa pegar vários fatores. Você também complicou tudo, quis colocar um bat e um download ftp na mesma thread! Um pouco de malícia e com o mesmo esqueleto você tem um trojan.

Comment: Mais 3 funções e você tem um RAT aí. Mas o importante é atualizar o sistema do cliente! haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não é o único a enfrentar esse problema, veja [**este tópico**](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:nFU77tvtwPYJ:forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=138435.15) do fórum do Avast. O antivírus está detectando o seu aplicativo como sendo um [trojan downloader](http://www.wiki-security.com/wiki/Parasite/TrojanDownloader), ele está certo em fazer isso.

Para contornar o problema, o **correto** é entrar em contato com o fabricante do antivírus e reportar o falso positivo. Clique [**aqui**](http://www.avast.com/pt-br/contact-form.php) para abrir o formulário de contato do Avast.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma tentativa que pode ser eficaz é chamar a função que aciona o antivírus de forma dinâmica. A função [`FtpGetFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384157%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) da *unit* `WinInet` tem o mesmo objetivo que o método `Get` do `IdFtp`.

Carregando a função `FtpGetFile` de forma dinâmica:

```pascal
Uses Windows;

const
WNETDLL = 'wininet.dll';
WNETFNC = 'FtpGetFileW';

implementation

type
  HINTERNET = Pointer;
  PHINTERNET = ^HINTERNET;
  LPHINTERNET = PHINTERNET;
  INTERNET_PORT = Word;
  PINTERNET_PORT = ^INTERNET_PORT;
  LPINTERNET_PORT = PINTERNET_PORT;

function MyFtpGetFile(hConnect: HINTERNET; lpszRemoteFile: LPWSTR;
  lpszNewFile: LPWSTR; fFailIfExists: BOOL; dwFlagsAndAttributes: DWORD;
  dwFlags: DWORD; dwContext: DWORD_PTR): BOOL;
Var
 F: function(hConnect: HINTERNET; lpszRemoteFile: LPWSTR;
  lpszNewFile: LPWSTR; fFailIfExists: BOOL; dwFlagsAndAttributes: DWORD;
  dwFlags: DWORD; dwContext: DWORD_PTR): BOOL stdcall;
begin
  F := GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary(pchar(WNETDLL)), pchar(WNETFNC));
  Result := F(hConnect, lpszRemoteFile, lpszNewFile, fFailIfExists, dwFlagsAndAttributes,
  dwFlags, dwContext);
end;
```

Segue um exemplo de utilização da função [`FtpGetFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384157%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```pascal
Uses Windows, WinInet;

const FtpUrl = 'ftp://ftp.foo.bar/';
const FtpServer = 'ftp.foo.bar';

Function DownloadFtp(const Usuario, Senha, RemoteFile, LocalFile: string): Boolean;
Var
 HI, FI: HINTERNET;
Begin
Result := False;
Try
 HI := InternetOpen('Ftp', INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, nil, nil, 0);
 if Assigned(HI) then
   FI := InternetConnect(HI, pchar(FtpServer), INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT,
   pchar(Usuario), pchar(Senha), INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);

   Result := FtpGetFile(fi, PChar(RemoteFile), PChar(LocalFile), False, 0,
   FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII, 0); // Neste exemplo será baixado um arquivo de texto
Finally
 InternetCloseHandle(HI);
 InternetCloseHandle(FI);
End;
End;
```

Em um botão coloque o código:

```pascal
Var
 Descarregado: Boolean;
begin
 Descarregado:= DownloadFtp('', '', '/remoteFile.txt', 'localFile.txt');
 if Descarregado then
   ShowMessage('Arquivo baixado com sucesso!')
 else
   ShowMessage('Erro ao baixar arquivo.');
```

Neste exemplo vai ser baixado um arquivo de texto *ftp://ftp.foo.bar/remoteFile.txt* e salvará no diretório do executável com o nome *localFile.txt*.

Basicamente é isso, tem como implementar muito mais coisas, para mais informações a respeito do assunto, leia o artigo abaixo:

- [**Ftp programming com WinInet no Delphi**](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/delphi/wininet.htm).